# Is there a way to set a tkinter object font to a variable or open?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a problem in Python.
Usually, in tkinter objects, the "font" option is a string. But I want it to be a variable or an open().
I tried to set an open:

```
 SystemFont = open("/home/pi/Desktop/___/.SystemFnt.txt")
```

Then, I tried to set the font option to the open, like this:

```
lbl1 = Label(root2, text="My Apps:", font=SystemFont)
```

I keep getting this error in return. I assume it wants an integer instead.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/___/____.py", line 24, in LogInCmd
    lbl1 = Label(root2, text="My Apps:", font=SystemFont)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3148, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "name='/home/pi/Desktop/____/.SystemFnt.txt'"
```

I want to place down an `open()`, not an integer, though.

Comment: I don't get why `open()` can be linked to `font`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: No, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do on `open()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `tkinter.font.Font`.  Assign `font` option to an instance of `tkinter.font.Font`, you can change the font family and size dynamically.

Below is an example of changing font family and size of a label dynamically:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

def change_font_family(val):
    font['family'] = val

def change_font_size(val):
    font['size'] = val

root = tk.Tk()

panel = tk.Frame(root, width=1000, height=300)
panel.pack()

font = Font(family='Arial', size=24)
lbl = tk.Label(panel, text='Hello World', font=font)
lbl.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# select font family
families = ('Arial', 'Times', 'Consolas', 'Calibri')
family_var = tk.StringVar()
opt_family = tk.OptionMenu(root, family_var, *families, command=change_font_family)
opt_family.pack()
opt_family.config(width=20)

# select font size
opt_size = tk.Scale(root, from_=10, to_=100, orient='horizontal', length=300, command=change_font_size)
opt_size.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is it possible to assign tkinter.font.Font to a variable? I don't want to do a open() anymore.

Comment: @MP888 I have already assigned it to a variable on the line: `font = Font(family='Arial', size=24)`.  And I don't use any `open()`.  What do you mean actually?

Comment: So maybe this is the required code, for example: button = Button(root, text="ExampleButton", font=font*)                                                                                               *Instead of font, I'll use a different name for the variable.

Comment: Then simply use other name: `my_font = Font(...)`.